# Set up stunnel to wrap SSL for a single application

Tags: stunnel

I am trying to use [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org) to get an older usenet client to support SSL.  I tried the following config:

```
[myservice]
accept = <LOCAL_PORT>
connect = <REMOTE_HOST>:<REMOTE_PORT>
```

but stunnel kept failing with the error:

```
Section myservice: SSL server needs a certificate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `client = yes` in the `[myservice]` section.  This tells stunnel that the `connect` (aka "server") side is the SSL one and the `accept` (aka "client") side is plain.  The default is the opposite, which requires an SSL certificate.

But that's not all!  For some insane reason, stunnel defaults to completely insecure mode that does no verification of the server's certificates, which means that you would be subject to man-in-the-middle (MitM) attacks!  To fix this, use the `verify = 2` and `CAfile` options.    On Ubuntu, the `CAfile` can be found at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` (from the `ca-certificates` package).  While you're at it, also set `options = NO_SSLv2` to disable the insecure SSLv2 protocol.

Finally, when you configure your usenet program, disable SSL, since the connection between the application and stunnel does NOT use SSL.

I wrote the following wrapper script to help with this.  Replace `<LOCAL_PORT>`, `<REMOTE_HOST>`, and `<REMOTE_PORT>` as appropriate, and replace `# ...` with whatever command you want to run.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
PIDFILE=/tmp/stunnel-agent.pid

# Start stunnel in the background.
cat << EOF | stunnel4 -fd 0
pid = $PIDFILE

# Enable proper SSL security.  Without this, you are completely insecure!
verify = 2
CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
options = NO_SSLv2

[myservice]
client = yes
accept = <LOCAL_PORT>
connect = <REMOTE_HOST>:<REMOTE_PORT>
EOF

# Start whatever program you want.
# ...

# Kill stunnel.
kill $(cat "$PIDFILE")
```